# Find total of marks for each student in the given file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files

the file:

```
Name: Rad
Eng: 94
Tam: 98
Mat: 98
Soc: 98
Sci: 80
Name: Din
Eng: 87
Tam: 89
Mat: 78
Soc: 87
Sci: 34
Name: Hardy
Eng: 78
Tam: 87
Mat: 23
Soc: 34
Sci: 98
```

the script :

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
num=$2
n=`wc -l < $file`
it=$((n/num))
echo $n
echo $it
awk -v numm="$num" '{if (NR<=numm){T+=$2}}END{print T}' $file
```

My above script could generate total for first student.
I want to find total for remaining two students marks also.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for `Name` and every time is found you go to the next `numm` lines and sum the scores:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
num=$2
awk -v numm="$num" '
/Name/{
  mark = 0;
  printf("%s ",$2);
  for ( i=0; i<numm ; i++){
    getline;
    mark += $2;
  }
  printf("%d\n", mark);
}' $file
```

the result:

```
Rad 468
Din 375
Hardy 320
```

Comment: I able to understand this. Thank you so much..! so getline within for loop will always fetch the next line?

Comment: your welcome ! yes, every time `getline` is execute `awk` goes to the next line.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/^Name:/ { if (name) printf("%s, score = %d\n", name, score); name = $2; score = 0; next }
              { score += $2 }
     END      { printf("%s, score = %d\n", name, score) }' file
```

Result:

```
Rad, score = 468
Din, score = 375
Hardy, score = 320
```

The first `awk` block is executed for each line that starts with the string `Name:`. If the `name` variable has a value, then the summed up score for the previous student is printed along with the student's name. Then the name is set to the second field of the current line and the score is reset to zero. The script then immediately continues with the next input line.

The second block is executed for every row of input that is not handled by the previous block.  It simply adds the score to the value of the `score` variable.

The last block executes after reading the final line of the file and mimics the outputting done in the first block.  This is so that the last student's result is outputted.

---

Duplicating code is ugly, so here's a solution that uses a function for doing the output:

```
awk 'function output() { if (name) printf("%s, score = %d\n", name, score) } 
     /^Name:/          { output(); name = $2; score = 0; next }
                       { score += $2 }
     END               { output() }' file
```

---

This was not part of the question, but might be interesting:

```
awk 'function output() { if (name) printf("%s\t score = %3d, mean = %.1f\n", name, score, score/count) } 
     /^Name:/          { output(); name = $2; score = count = 0; next }
                       { score += $2; ++count }
     END               { output() }' file
```

Output:

```
Rad      score = 468, mean = 93.6
Din      score = 375, mean = 75.0
Hardy    score = 320, mean = 64.0
```

Comment: This is little bit confusing for me.  Will the first name be stored in the variable 'name' before assigning name=$2. Does the result are printed from END block are from IF block? Can you please help me to understand better. I am not able to get what you explained. this command looks difficult for me to understand. Reagrds, Radhakrishnan

Comment: @RadhakrishnanRk When the `awk` code reads the very first line of the file, `name` will initially be empty, no output happens (since `name` is empty), but `name` gets the value from `$2`. When the second `Name:` line is found, the collected data for the _first_ person is printed, and `name` is set to the name of the second person. In the `END` block, the collected data for the _last_ person in the file is printed.

Comment: Yes. I am getting that name is empty. But I could not get how previous person score is printed? I have following doubts too.. what 'next' performs? 'score +=$2' executed till next occurrence of Name? So printf from IF block printed how many output? and printf from END block printed how many lines?

Comment: @RadhakrishnanRk The `next` command will make the program immediately jump to the beginning of the script and read the next line from the input data. If we have found a `Name:` line, the rest of the program is irrelevant for that particular line, so I use `next` to continue with the next line.

Comment: @RadhakrishnanRk The `END` block will print at most one line of output (that for the last student). The rest of the output happens in the earlier block.

Comment: @RadhakrishnanRk Yes, every block is applied to the current input line if it matches the corresponding pattern. If the `next` command is executed, however, the script continues from the beginning with the next input line.

Comment: Understood with END block printf. But 'next' command utility is not understandable. May be I am missing the logic behind curly braces {}. Why 'if (name) printf("%s, score = %d\n", name, score:)'and 'name = $2;' and 'score = 0;' and 'next' are enclosed in same curly braces when ' score += $2' is enclosed in an another curly braces?

Comment: So i) printf("%s, score = %d\n", name, score) ii)name = $2;iii) score = 0; iv) next -- all these four will be executed only when /Name/ occurs ? And remaining line score +=$2 executes for all input lines except those lines matching /Name/. Am I in right way? This exception is done using 'next'

Comment: @RadhakrishnanRk You are entirely correct (in that last comment). Awk scripts are built using patterns and actions. An action is what's in a `{...}` block. An action without a pattern will be executed for every line.

Comment: Thank you so much for showing patience in clarifying my doubts. :-)

Comment: @RadhakrishnanRk Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below command to achieve the same

command:

```
 for i in Rad Din Hardy
> do
> sed -n "/$i/,+5p" p.txt| awk -F ":" '{print $2}'| sed "/$i/d"| awk -v i="$i" 'BEGIN{sum=0}{sum=sum+$1}END {print "Total marks of " i " "  sum}'
> done
```

output

```
Total marks of Rad 468
Total marks of Din 375
Total marks of Hardy 320
```